# Homotopy Classification of Torus Maps

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In problem 8-11 of Lee's "Intro to Topological Manifolds", the reader is asked to show that for every continuous $\phi:\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$, there is a $2\times 2$ integer matrix $D(\phi)$ with the following properties:

1. $\phi,\psi$ are homotopic iff. $D(\phi)=D(\psi)$
2. $D(\psi\circ\phi)=D(\psi)D(\phi)$
3. For every $2\times 2$ integer matrix $E$, there is a continuous $\phi$ with $D(\phi)=E$
4. $\phi$ is homotopic to a homeomorphism iff. $D(\phi)\in GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

This is clearly some analogue of the degree of a map, as introduced in the book for maps from the circle to itself. Since $\mathbb{T}^2=S^1\times S^1$, the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and so endomorphisms of $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2)$ are indeed $2\times 2$ integer matrices. I have shown, without constructing such a matrix explicitly, that they satisfy 1) and 2). For 3), however, I am not sure how to do this without explicitly constructing the matrix for a given map $\phi$, and I am unsure how to construct this matrix. It is clearly related to the winding number of the map around the torus, but from that I can only extract two integers, as far as I can tell.
How would I construct this matrix, or alternatively, how could I prove that every endomorphism has at least one associated map?

Comment: Consider a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ given by a $2\times 2$ integer matrix. Since this sends $\mathbb Z^2 $ to itself, we get a map from $\mathbb R^2/ \mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2/ \mathbb Z^2$

Comment: I fully agree with that, but how does that help in showing that every such matrix corresponds to at least one continuous function from the torus to itself?

Comment: Soumik started from an integer matrix and constructed a continuous function. Can you show that this continuous function works ? (by the way, this construction together with point 1. will give an answer to point 4.)

Comment: Oh I see, because linear maps are continuous. That  makes perfect sense, I had not thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: how did you solve 1?

Comment: By mimicking the constructions in the section on "Degree theory of the Circle" but using endomorphisms instead of explicit circle maps. The proofs are then almost the same, and in particular proposition 8.15 in the book.